# Flipboard or iBooks style animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

Are there any examples out there to emulate page turning like iBooks or Flipboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to wait for iOS 5 (hint, hint).  You can check out the WWDC iOS 5 videos (for free) if you are a registered developer (for instance "What's new in Cocoa Touch").

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/

Comment: Documentation: [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html).

Answer (score 7):

YES,

I saw this the other day on github.

http://github.com/brow/leaves
"An iBooks like" page turning interface.

Comment: It's not a "real" leaves effect, it's static, but not that bad. The iBooks Effect is private API.

Comment: Btw, as of iOS5, Apple added UIPageViewController, so it now can be used w/o touching private API (well, more or less, since UIPageViewController is horribly buggy in iOS5, but that's another story. I got it working in PSPDFKit, after a lot of pain)

Answer (score 1):

If you're into Math and OpenGL, there is a Page that explains how it can be made.

http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html