# PDF Reader like iBooks

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipad

I want to create a PDF reader like iBooks. So that you can see the thumbnails for the pages, press on it and it opens the page etcetera. Also the bookshelf for showing the loaded PDF's

Does anyone know how I can create something like that? Is there a library or does somebody knows a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance!

What I need is something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the page curl, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836813/does-core-animation-provide-public-apis-for-ibook-style-page-curl-page-transition). For everything else, you should break the problem down into more focused questions since it's hard to tell how much detail to give (ie, we don't know how much you already know).

**Update**

For the drawing part, start with the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [Views Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). I believe you can get basic PDF thumbnails using the [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/) class.

Comment: Well what I want to know to start for is how I can make a bookshelf which displays a couple of PDF's and when you press on it, how can I show thumbnails of the pages of the selected pdf file

Comment: So to start, how can I create thumbnails from pdf and show them like iBooks so you can see the pages and you can press on it...

Comment: Updated. You'll need your own artwork but the drawing and views programming guides contain most of what you need to understand how to do drawing in basic custom views.

Comment: I need something like the picture above.. Isn't there a good tutorial about this?

Comment: You might start with AQGridView: http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/528737778/aqgridview-lives-for-my-ipad-dev-camp-hackathon for a quick start. As for extracting PDF thumbnails, read the UIImage class reference I linked you to. You're not going to get anywhere by ignoring the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This opensource project is the exact copy of the iBook pdf reader:

http://www.vfr.org/