# pdf reader in iphone

Tags: ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF Reader like iBooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187031/pdf-reader-like-ibooks)

hi there i am trying to make a pdf reader for iphone 
so can anybody help me out

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UIWebView as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview) to display your pdf.

However, if you want to generate a pdf, you can find more information [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file)

(I consider this post as a duplicate)